# Switch on the Always open Read only under protect workbook in Excel using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, automation

I  want to turn on the - always read only option under the Protect Workbook in Excel file using the PowerShell command

Excel file- file-info-Protect workbook-Always open read only

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJBK6.png)

It will be helpful if any one share the script

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/6.0.0/Content/Set-WorkSheetProtection.ps1